# Find best MA that fits an index

Tags: r, trading, quantstrat

I would lke to find the best Moving average, one for buy and one for sale, that fits an index or a stock. Is it possible using the R package `Quantstrat`? 
Could someone give an example how this is done in R?

Comment: Again, quantstrat has many demos.  Or see http://www.r-programming.org/papers

Comment: Might be obvious to quants and fintech people, but... By "best," do you mean, "profit-maximizing"? But wouldn't that depend on the entry and exit strategy too, not just the window of the moving average (which is what I'm assuming you're trying to optimize)? What constitutes a "best" moving average? Again, asking out of curiosity, not knocking the question.